# Why filter function cannot pickeled?

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to merge two lists in python the filter this obtained list.

I have following dataframe df:

```
+---+--------+
|v1 | v2 | v |
+---+--------+
|  2|   4| 24|
|  4|   2| 42|
|  1|   1| 11|
|  1|   3| 13|
|  2|   2| 22|
+---+----+---+
```

And I have two brodcast variables (collectAsMap):

- t1: `{'3': ['4'], '1': ['2', '4', '3'], '2': ['3', '4']}`
- t2:  `{'3': ['4'], '5': ['6'], '1': ['2']}`

I tried the following in order to filter and merge the list

```
merge_udf = udf(merge, ArrayType(StringType()))
df = df.distinct().withColumn('MergeList', merge_udf(df.v1, df.v2)
```

where:

```
"""merge two lists in one list"""
def merge2List(listA, listB):
    merge = [(itemA+itemB) for itemA in listA for itemB in listB]
    return merge

"""merge the entry of two entries of dataframes"""
def merge(x, y):
    listA = t1.value.get(x)
    if(listA is None):
        listA = []
        listA.append(x)

    listB = t2.value.get(y)
    if(listB is None):
        listB = []
        listB.append(y)
    m = merge2List(listA, listB)
    return m
```

The obtained result is the following:

```
+---+---------+------------+
|v1 |v2       |   MergeList|
+---+---------+------------+
|  2|        4|    [34, 44]|
|  4|        2|        [42]|
|  1|        1|[22, 42, 32]|
|  1|        3|[24, 44, 34]|
|  2|        2|    [32, 42]|
+---+---------+------------+
```

I have a t3 brodcast variable where `print(list(t3.value.keys()))` gives `['24', '42', '11', '13', '22']`

Now I want to filter out the element in each list in the merge list column. Thus, I create the following function and update the merge2List function:

```
def filterList(v):
    vert = list(t3.value.keys())
    if(v in vert):
        return True
    return False


"""merge two lists in one list"""
    def merge2List(listA, listB):
        merge = [(itemA+itemB) for itemA in listA for itemB in listB]
        filteredList = filter(filterList, merge)
        return filteredList
```

The following exception is raised:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function filterList at 0x2b2fb1aa6840>: attribute lookup filterList on __main__ failed
```

Can someone help in identifing where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Since filter is evaluating lazily, the pickle cannot read the values. Because they do not exist, yet. It returns an iterator. Try:

```
filtered = filter(m_func, m_list)
pickle.dumps(list(filtered))
```

Comment: No exception is raised but I get in all the mergeList column the following strange values:`[-128, 3, 93, 113...]`

Comment: @moudi let me check if there is another bug.

Comment: @moudi i could not find anything. could you try printing before and after filter.

Comment: `print("\n=================filter==============",pickle.dumps(list(filteredList)))` prints:` =================filter============== b'\x80\x03]q\x00X\x02\x00\x00\x0042q\x01a.'`

Comment: `pickle.loads(b'\x80\x03]q\x00X\x02\x00\x00\x0042q\x01a.')`
returns `['42']`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(list(filteredList)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers above are correct. But I manage as following to solve the problem:

```
def merge2List(listA, listB):
    merge = [(itemA+itemB) for itemA in listA for itemB in listB]
    filteredList = filter(lambda x: x in list(t3.value.keys()), merge)
    return list(filteredList)
```